# what is boot image in the DHCP

Tags: dhcp

I read in the e.comer book that in dhcp the dhcp allow a computee to negotiate to find a boot image and to do so the host fills in field boot file name with the request and dhcp server does not send an image
I realy can not understand a single word
Need help

Answer (score 0):

well simply put:
you can not only boot from hard disks or pen drives, but also from the network.
in this case the dhcp assigns you a boot image file path, the network card loads that file, and then boots it.

Comment: Okey my question is what is the boot images

Comment: im not sure if i understand your question. do you want to know what a boot image is in general?